# Save any Clipboard content and reload it?

Tags: c#, clipboard, clipboarddata

I need to use clipboard memory for 1 sec, doing some stuff, and reload the clipboard as original.

I want my cliboard do :

- "original random text, image, sound or anything else" --> "My Useful Text"
- "My Useful Text" --> "random text, image, sound or anything else"

But what my clipboard do :

- "original random text, image, sound or anything else" --> "My Useful Text"
- "My Useful Text"                           --> " " [nothing]

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ExplorerTools 
{
  public void Run()
  {
    // saving the current clipboard
    var oldClipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    // Doing some stuff with the clipboard
    Clipboard.SetText("My Useful Text");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);

    // I want to put back oldClipboard in the clipboard
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(oldClipboard);
  }
}
```

I don't understand why `Clipboard.SetDataObject()` cannot retrieve the old value, he just put nothing ='(

Comment: Please note that the clipboard is meant for the convenience of the human user.  It's not a good mechanism for automated data transfer between programs.

Comment: Did you use the debugger to inspect the oldClipboard value? - If you do you'll find that..: _Because the data type of the object returned from the Clipboard can vary, this method returns the data in an IDataObject. Then you can use methods of the IDataObject interface to extract the data in its proper data type._

Comment: @BenVoigt you have right, but there is another way to get any selected text from any program ? imagine config file with a path to another file...  i want to select the path, and ask my program to open it directly. The only way I see is to send a Ctrl+C event and read what I fished. But I'm open to other solution.

Comment: @Taw hmm... I was afraid to pass a long time to code every 21 kind of the clipboard data [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataformats?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), but y success to avoid it ^^

Comment: Well if you really know that it is just text you need to save/restore it will be a lot easier but my guess is that you don't know that and want to restore anything, which may well include proprietary (!) objects frm other apps. So avoidíng the whole issue may well be the best option.

Comment: @Taw The proprietary objects should work, but i'm afraid about the property "when app ended, the memory must be release or kept", don't be conserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Taw said, i can't directly use the IDataObject i get from `Clipboard.GetDataObject()`. So I have to save every 21 kind of clipboard data and reload it individually myself.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ExplorerTools 
{
  public void Run()
  {
    // saving the current clipboard
    string[] arr_format = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats(false);
    Dictionary<string, object> dic_oldDataClipboard = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach(string format in arr_format)
      dic_oldDataClipboard.Add(format, Clipboard.GetData(format));


    // Doing some stuff with the clipboard
    Clipboard.SetText("My Useful Text");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);


    // I want to put back oldClipboard in the clipboard
    foreach(var format_data in dic_oldDataClipboard)
      Clipboard.SetData(format_data.Key, format_data.Value);
  }
}
```